# CSS transition property not working on header tag

Tags: html, css, header, transition, sticky

Could someone tell me why the transition property doesn't seem to be working on the header tag on my website:  http://www.hccoinc.com/about/

I have a sticky (fixed) menu that I shrink after scrolling a ways.  Everything is working except the transition property on the menu - the height change should transition over 0.3s, but it's happening immediately.

Here's the html structure:

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="site-branding" rel="home" title="HCCO, Inc. (WOSB)" href="http://www.hccoinc.com/">
      <h1 class="site-title">
      <h2 class="site-description">Piecing IT Together</h2>
    </a>
    <nav id="site-navigation" class="site-primary-navigation slide-left">
      ...
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Here's the relevant CSS:

```
.site-header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.site-main {
  margin-top: 107px;
}

header, header .site-title img {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

header.site-header.smaller {
  height: 55px;
  background: rgba(51, 153, 204, 0.93);
}

header.site-header.smaller .container {
  padding: 0;
}

header.site-header.smaller .site-title img {
  max-height: 54px;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: what triggers the transition ?

Comment: You didn't give the transitions timing to the .site-header

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I had to apply the background color the .container div for other reasons, then I applied the transition timing to .container height and it's working now.